# How To Delete Element by class (Native Method)

Tags: javascript, html, dom

```
    function reloadItems()
    {
        var docBody = document.body;
        docBody.removeChild(document.getElementsByClassName("itemsLayout"));
    }
```

I'm Using This Code to delete an element in my DOM, but once i fire the code nothing happen, I'm using XAMPP Local Server and don't know the reason of this bug

"This element is a direct child in the body of the DOM"

Comment: try `element.parentNode.removeChild(element);`

Comment: I find it hard to believe that "nothing happen". You should have gotten a console error such as "Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'." Were you watching the console?

Comment: This question is neither "a typo" or "no-repro," to paraphrase the first part of the given close-reason. I'd also argue that it is on-topic, despite not being a great, or particularly challenging, question. Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`removeChild()` expects a *child* (singular), and will only work on single nodes at a time; that being the case you'll need to use a loop:

```
function reloadItems() {
    var docBody = document.body,
        items = document.getElementsByClassName('itemsLayout');
    while (items.length) {
        items[0].parentNode.removeChild(items[0]);
    }
}
```

Incidentally, `getElementsByClassName()`, thanks to Internet Explorer 8, is less supported than `querySelectorAll()`, so I'd suggest switching to:

```
function reloadItems() {
    var docBody = document.body,
        items = document.querySelectorAll('.itemsLayout');
    while (items.length) {
        items[0].parentNode.removeChild(items[0]);
    }
}
```

References:

- [`document.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.getElementsByClassName).
- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll).
- [`Node.removeChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.removeChild).

Comment: is there anything that removes the whole element directly ?

Comment: What's the 'whole element' you're referring to?

Comment: For example this div, is there any function to remove it directly ?

Comment: Okay: by 'this div' you mean the items we're looping over (the `items[0]` elements)? Or the element in which they're contained?